# XML Transformation in Sitecore Identity Server using Docker

Tags: docker, identity-server

We have to modify some changes in the Sitecore identity server's `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host` file using docker.

This file remains present at the location `xp01.localidentityserver.dev.local\Config\production`.

We want to modify the domain name with the new domain name, using XML transformation, as you can see in the config below **[new-domain-name]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>
      <CertificateThumbprint>AA69xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3A231</CertificateThumbprint>
      <CertificateStoreLocation>LocalMachine</CertificateStoreLocation>
      <CertificateStoreName>My</CertificateStoreName>
      <SitecoreMembershipOptions>
        <ConnectionString>Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=xxxxx_Core;User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=******</ConnectionString>
      </SitecoreMembershipOptions>
      <AccountOptions>
        <PasswordRecoveryUrl>https://[new-domain-name]/sitecore/login?rc=1</PasswordRecoveryUrl>
      </AccountOptions>
      <Clients>
        <DefaultClient>
          <AllowedCorsOrigins>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://[new-domain-name]</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
          </AllowedCorsOrigins>
        </DefaultClient>
        <PasswordClient>
          <ClientSecrets>
            <ClientSecret1>IdentityServerClientSecret</ClientSecret1>
          </ClientSecrets>
        </PasswordClient>
      </Clients>
    </IdentityServer>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

How to perform this activity so that when we deploy this using docker and CI/CD on different environments (dev, uat and prod) then this [new-domain-name] should be according to that.

If with the Sitecore docker, there is any way other than transformation please suggest that as well. We are using `Sitecore 10.2` with `SXA`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding this to your `docker-compose.override.xml` file like below.

```
Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__DefaultClient__AllowedCorsOrigins__AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1: https://${HRZ_HOST}
```

Here is how it is being added to the file.

```
id:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-id:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/id
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp1-cd:${SITECORE_VERSION}        
        TOOLING_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_TOOLS_REGISTRY}sitecore-docker-tools-assets:${TOOLS_VERSION}
        SOLUTION_IMAGE: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-solution:${VERSION:-latest}
    depends_on:
      - solution
    environment: 
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__DefaultClient__AllowedCorsOrigins__AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1: https://${HRZ_HOST}
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_DEPLOY_PATH}\identity:C:\deploy
    entrypoint: powershell -Command "& C:\tools\entrypoints\worker\Development.ps1"
```

Then try building and see if it works for you.

Comment: so do you suggest adding one more domain like ${HRZ_HOST}, if yes then will it take the comma separated list?

Comment: Yes you can add it something like this. https://github.com/coveooss/sitecore-docker-examples/blob/develop/custom-images/.env

And here is how the solution is implemented. 

https://github.com/coveooss/sitecore-docker-examples/tree/develop/custom-images

Answer (score 1):

**You can use XSLT transformation to transform XML files.**

For that, create a `.xslt` file and paste the below transformations.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//IdentityServer/AccountOptions">
    <xsl:copy>
       <PasswordRecoveryUrl>https://[new-domain-name]/sitecore/login?rc=1 </PasswordRecoveryUrl>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="//IdentityServer/Clients/DefaultClient/AllowedCorsOrigins">
    <xsl:copy>
       <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://[new-domain-name]</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After that, Open the `dockerfile` of the ID role, and map the XSLT file to ID image.

```
COPY ./<path of XSLT folder>/Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xslt /Config/production/Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xslt
```